# flutter setState toggles scaffold bottomSheet

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a simple code snippet here demonstrating a possible issue or lack of understanding on my end. I tested this on android and chrome. A persistent bottomsheet in a page route toggles open/closed when setState is called. My intention is for the bottomsheet to always be open when on this page - is there something I'm missing for that? A scaffold property maybe or some bottomSheet specific containing element?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Test createState() => _Test();
}

class _Test extends State<Test> {
  int count = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("appbar")),
        body: RaisedButton(
          child: Text("count $count"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              count = count + 1;
            });
          },
        ),
        bottomSheet: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          height: 300,
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been a bug with the version of the beta I was on from a few weeks ago. I have run flutter upgrade and it's gone. If anyone comes across a similar issue with routing/navigation while the new routing system is rolled out, hopefully it's possible to either switch to the stable channel or upgrade the beta.